# Position of "number of products per page" option

Tags: website-design

I'm working on a marketplace (buyer-to-buyer) website. What is the best practice to put "number of products per page" option? Is it better to put it on top of the products rows or under? Anyway, which is more easier for user, to use "number of products per page" options or "show more"/"show all" or anything else?

Also if not too demanding I want to ask you for examples of marketplace(s) with tidy and aesthetically pleasing design that you known of, because the number of marketplaces with good ui design in my country is very limited. (Is this stackexchange website the right place to ask for references?)

Thank you! :)

Comment: For really aesthetically pleasing and functional online marketplaces, I'd suggest you take a look at [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com) and [Snapdeal](http://www.snapdeal.com).

Comment: What is your reasoning for having a 'number of products per page' option? There are a lot of sites that don't offer that functionality, I wonder what the arguments might be.

Comment: Actually I'm thinking of this because my company old design have this option. Now I want to consider other options to show more product, like "show all" etc. For @ikartik90 thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's no real overhead to have it at both ends of the product list, thus if the user is at the bottom, they don't need to scroll to the top to change the value. Furthermore, it sits, logically, with the paging.

Comment: Thank you! Btw, is it better to use "number of products per page" or "show all"/"show more" according to your experience? Thank you again :))

Comment: @Rosiana I'd suggest to use a lazy loader instead of paginating the website. That way, you could optimize the number of products you wish to load at a time and in case the user ends up reaching the end of the currently loaded list, new products would automatically load following the current end of list (the way facebook loads more posts once the user reaches the end of the list). This would enhance usability by reducing the number of clicks required to for the user to achieve their objective.

Comment: @ikartik90 Did you mean like Snapdeal? Yeah the method surely easier for users. It also looks very elegant and simple, a really good reference. Thank you!

Comment: The one downside to lazy loader is when your list could grow exponentially, in that situation a "back to the top" link is useful.

Answer (score 0):

if i had to chose then I'd place it at the top, above the list of products. Reason: it's is much harder to find that setting if I have to scroll down to a location below all the products.

But on the other hand, why not place that setting both above and below the list of products?

Sorry that I cannot provide you with any good examples.

Comment: It's okay, thank you! :) Btw, is it better to use "number of products per page" or "show all"/"show more" according to your experience? Thank you again :))

Comment: For mobile users, I'd prefer "Show more". As a web developer, you do not have to force the user to download all the data, just the relevant amount of products. So some kind of "Show 25 more items" in combination with "Show all ithems (518)" might be a good solution.